# EF Code First "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" but no inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table in my database called SEntries (see below the CREATE TABLE statement). It has a primary key, a couple of foreign keys and nothing special about it. I have many tables in my database similar to that one, but for some reason, this table ended up with a "Discriminator" column on the EF Proxy Class.

This is how the class is declared in C#:

```
public class SEntry
{
    public long SEntryId { get; set; }

    public long OriginatorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public byte DataEntrySource { get; set; }
    public string SourceLink { get; set; }
    public int SourceAppId { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public long? ActivityId { get; set; }
    public short OriginatorObjectTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class EMData : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SEntry> SEntries { get; set; }
            ...
    }
```

When I try to add a new row to that table, I get the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
```

This problem only occurs if you are inheriting your C# class from another class, but SEntry is not inheriting from anything (as you can see above).

In addition to that, once I get the tool-tip on the debugger when I mouse over the EMData instance for the SEntries property, it displays:

```
base {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<EM.SEntry>} = {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[SEntryId] AS [SEntryId], 
[Extent1].[OriginatorId] AS [OriginatorId], 
[Extent1].[DatePosted] AS [DatePosted], 
[Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
[Extent1].[DataEntrySource] AS [DataE...
```

Any suggestions or ideas where to get to the bottom of this issue? I tried renaming the table, the primary key and a few other things, but nothing works.

SQL-Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SEntries](
[SEntryId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1125899906842624,1) NOT NULL,
[OriginatorId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[DatePosted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Message] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[DataEntrySource] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[SourceLink] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[SourceAppId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LocationId] [int] NULL,
[ActivityId] [bigint] NULL,
[OriginatorObjectTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SEntries]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SEntries_ObjectTypes] FOREIGN KEY([OriginatorObjectTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectTypes] ([ObjectTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SEntries] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SEntries_ObjectTypes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SEntries]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SEntries_SourceApps] FOREIGN KEY([SourceAppId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SourceApps] ([SourceAppId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SEntries] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SEntries_SourceApps]
GO
```

Comment: For the next person who'll spend some time trying to figure this out, what happened is that in another place on the code, I had a class that inherited from SEntry, even though it's not a class that would ever be stored on the DB. So all that I needed to do was to add [NotMapped] as an attribute of that class!

Comment: I am getting this error if i don't put [NotMapped] on ApplicationUser class in Identitymodel.cs

Comment: I have a similar issue, posted in detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75333465/using-inherited-entity-class-in-asp-net-ef-core

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Turns out that Entity Framework will assume that any class that inherits from a POCO class that is mapped to a table on the database requires a Discriminator column, even if the derived class will not be saved to the DB.

The solution is quite simple and you just need to add `[NotMapped]` as an attribute of the derived class.

Example:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[NotMapped]
class PersonViewModel : Person
{
    public bool UpdateProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Now, even if you map the Person class to the Person table on the database, a "Discriminator" column will not be created because the derived class has `[NotMapped]`.

As an additional tip, you can use `[NotMapped]` to properties you don't want to map to a field on the DB.

Comment: ok so there goes 3 hours of my life ;( but tyvm all the same. I should also add just to be clear... the derived classes can be all the way over in the corner not in any way used re: persistence and EF will still try and draw them in...very confusing.

Comment: If you don't find [NotMapped] please add a reference to: "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" to the project from "Assembly Framework".

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Comment: How to fix the error "Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType", when trying to add the viewmodel to the db collection?

Comment: OMG! I deliberately created a DTO class that inherits the Entity to avoid using NotMapped.... but NOooooooo... :( For some reason getting the Base Entity wants to upcast to my DTO.. I don't get it.. absurd.

Comment: but in my case I have inherited a class to add column in db table using child class. So I cant use this notmapped attribute to get it working. What should be my solution in this case?

Comment: in my case adding not mapped didn't helped. i have notmapped in all viewmodels

Comment: I am getting this error. So I added the field (ContactNumberTypeId) with a [NotMapped] and now it's says it can't find field ContactNumberTypeId1. And if I add that field it can't find ContactNumberTypeId2.

Comment: 9 years later and I am also getting this error. I do have a classed inheriting from the POCO and like Heemanshu I added [NotMapped] and it did not work.

Comment: Until I realized that I had multiple classes inheriting from my POCO class. Once I [NotMapped] them all, it worked. I tried to add this to my previous comment, but was stopped due to some time error

Comment: What if it is mapped though?

Answer (score 47):

Here is the Fluent API syntax.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { 
        get {
            return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
        }
    }
}

class PersonViewModel : Person
{
    public bool UpdateProfile { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ignore a type that is not mapped to a database table
    modelBuilder.Ignore<PersonViewModel>();

    // ignore a property that is not mapped to a database column
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Ignore(p => p.FullName);

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to add the `[NotMapped]` attribute?

Comment: @Keith my answer is how to ignore a column using the Fluent API, which does not use attributes such as [NotMapped]

Comment: Keith this is the preferred answer I think because are now moving towards a code-first standard and Walter's answer is better suited for this scenario especially if you end up using db migrations.

Comment: Where you have the opposite problem (i.e. and EF bound class that inherits from a POCO class) this was the only way I could get that to work without polluting the data model with EF.

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this and my problem was caused by having two entities both with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute` referring to the same table.

for example:

```
[Table("foo")]
public class foo
{
    // some stuff here
}

[Table("foo")]
public class fooExtended
{
    // more stuff here
}
```

changing the second one from `foo` to `foo_extended` fixed this for me and I'm now using Table Per Type (TPT)

Comment: This did not work for me:`The entity types 'AtencionMedica' and 'AtencionMedicaAP' cannot share table 'AtencionMedicas' because they are not in the same type hierarchy`

Comment: Thanks, helped me, had the same issue using the fluent API: `var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<EntityObject>().ToTable("ENTITY_TABLE")`, and then another line using either the same `EntityObject` or the same `ENTITY_TABLE`.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, not exactly the same conditions and then i saw [this post](http://www.dailycode.info/BlogV2/post/ef-oracle-and-ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator). Hope it helps someone. Apparently i was using one of my EF entity models a base class for a type that was not specified as a db set in my dbcontext. To fix this issue i had to create a base class that had all the properties common to the two types and inherit from the new base class among the two types.

Example:

```
//Bad Flow
    //class defined in dbcontext as a dbset
    public class Customer{ 
       public int Id {get; set;}
       public string Name {get; set;}
    }

    //class not defined in dbcontext as a dbset
    public class DuplicateCustomer:Customer{ 
       public object DuplicateId {get; set;}
    }


    //Good/Correct flow*
    //Common base class
    public class CustomerBase{ 
       public int Id {get; set;}
       public string Name {get; set;}
    }

    //entity model referenced in dbcontext as a dbset
    public class Customer: CustomerBase{

    }

    //entity model not referenced in dbcontext as a dbset
    public class DuplicateCustomer:CustomerBase{

       public object DuplicateId {get; set;}

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Another scenario where this occurs is when you have a base class and one or more subclasses, where at least one of the subclasses introduce extra properties:

```
class Folder {
  [key]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Adds no props, but comes from a different view in the db to Folder:
class SomeKindOfFolder: Folder {
}

// Adds some props, but comes from a different view in the db to Folder:
class AnotherKindOfFolder: Folder {
  public string FolderAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

If these are mapped in the `DbContext` like below, the "'Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" error occurs when any type based on `Folder` base type is accessed:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>().ToTable("All_Folders");
  modelBuilder.Entity<SomeKindOfFolder>().ToTable("Some_Kind_Of_Folders");
  modelBuilder.Entity<AnotherKindOfFolder>().ToTable("Another_Kind_Of_Folders");
}
```

I found that to fix the issue, we extract the props of `Folder` to a base class (which is not mapped in `OnModelCreating()`) like so - `OnModelCreating` should be unchanged:

```
class FolderBase {
  [key]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Folder: FolderBase {
}

class SomeKindOfFolder: FolderBase {
}

class AnotherKindOfFolder: FolderBase {
  public string FolderAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

This eliminates the issue, but I don't know why!

Comment: thanks, meataxe -- that cost me an hour or two, but the worst part was, I must have had this problem before, because I had the base classes all set up. Dumber me a year later says, "Hey, looks like this base class isn't doing anything. I think I'll just remove it..." And there went an hour of my life that I'll never get back. WHY IS THIS REQUIRED? I wish I understood EF better.

Answer (score 2):

I get the error in another situation, and here are the problem and the solution:

I have 2 classes derived from a same base class named LevledItem:

```
public partial class Team : LeveledItem
{
   //Everything is ok here!
}
public partial class Story : LeveledItem
{
   //Everything is ok here!
}
```

But in their DbContext, I copied some code but forget to change one of the class name:

```
public class MFCTeamDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Other codes here
        modelBuilder.Entity<LeveledItem>()
            .Map<Team>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(ItemType.Team));
    }

public class ProductBacklogDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Other codes here
        modelBuilder.Entity<LeveledItem>()
            .Map<Team>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(ItemType.Story));
    }
```

Yes, the second Map< Team> should be Map< Story>. 
And it cost me half a day to figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Old Q, but for posterity...it also also happens (.NET Core 2.1) if you have a self-referencing navigation property ("Parent" or "Children" of the same type) but the Id property name isn't what EF expects. That is, I had an "Id" property on my class called `WorkflowBase`, and it had an array of related child steps, which were also of type `WorkflowBase`, and it kept trying to associate them with a non-existent "WorkflowBaseId" (the name i suppose it prefers as a natural/conventional default). I had to explicitly configure it using `HasMany()`, `WithOne()`, and `HasConstraintName()` to tell it how to traverse. But I spent a few hours thinking the problem was in 'locally' mapping the object's primary key, which i attempted to fix a bunch of different ways but which was probably always working.

Answer (score 1):

this error happen with me because I did the following

1. I changed Column name of table in database
2. (I did not used `Update Model from database` in Edmx) I Renamed manually Property name to match the change in database schema
3. I did some refactoring to change name of the property in the class to be the same as database schema and models in Edmx

Although all of this, I got this error

so `what to do`

1. I Deleted the model from Edmx
2. Right Click and `Update Model from database`

this will regenerate the model, and entity framework `will` **not** `give you this error`

hope this help you