# Derived POCOs referencing same table - strange naming issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a "base" entity with some properties that's being used by a bunch of other stuff (repository patterns, queues, etc) in some shared libraries.  Mapped to a pluralized table.

I need to add a property to it for my specific implementation, and I want to reuse all the rest of the normal behaviors.

I derive a class:

```
public interface IItem {
    [Key]
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item : IItem {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IExtended {
    bool IsExtended { get; set; }
}

[Table("Items")]        // <-- my nemesis
public class ExtendedItem : Item, IExtended {
    [Column("_Extended")]
    public bool IsExtended { get; set; }
}
```

I set up the code-first context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {
        // manually creating the tables, no migrations
        Database.SetInitializer<EfQueueContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

- Without DataAnnotation `[Table]` I get exception "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" -- *okay, weird but [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553935/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator-but-no-inheritance)*
- With `[NotMapped]` I get exception "The entity type ExtendedItem is not part of the model for the current context" -- *okay, makes sense*
- With annotation `[Table("Item"]` I get exception "table 'dbo.Item' doesn't exist" -- *okay, duh forgot it pluralized original*
- With annotation `[Table("Items")]` I get exception "table 'dbo.Items1' doesn't exist" -- *what??? **where did the `1` suffix come from?***
- <del>Even creating a brand-new `DbContext` that only refers to `ExtendedItem` and not `Item` still adds the '1'</del> *(update - I didn't actually create a clean instance; see comment on answer)*

Comment: What if you use `[Table("Something")]` instead of "Items"? It might just conflict with the Item class.

Comment: I believe `class Item` receives table name `Items`. So for `class ExtendedItem` it should be something else, like `ExtendedItems`.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you want to keep Item and ExtendedItem in the same table Items? Make sure EF supports the way you want it to work. Not sure here.

Comment: Anyway, the source of the names conflict is the lack of annotation for class Item so it automatically receives a pluralized name Items.

Comment: @abatishchev You're supposed to be able to manually specify table names with annotations/fluent-api, but my real problem is that when I specify the exact, existing table name ("Items") something decided to append a "1" rather than use what I told it to.  I've update the question slightly to emphasize that problem.

Comment: Try applying the `[Table("Items")] ` annotation in both entities (`Item` and `ExtendedItem`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is EF deduce you want to create a [Table per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) when you apply the `Table` atribute on the subclasses to specify the mapped table name. In your case you are trying to rename the table related with the`ExtendedItem` entity, but you are using the same name of the root table, that's way EF is creating two tables one called `Items1` (because you already use the `Items` name in the inheriting entity) related to the `Item` entity and another called `Items` related to the `ExtentedItem` entity

If you want to create a [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) and you want to rename the root table, then you need to apply the `[Table("Items")]` data annotation on the root entity (`Item`) and all entities that inherit from it.

Comment: This sounds right -- I didn't actually try it, because I found out I was accidentally inheriting the original `MyContext` rather than from `DbContext`, meaning that both `Item` and `ExtendedItem` were `DbSets`.  Once I started from a fresh `DbContext` without `Item` declared, I only needed to rename `ExtendedItem`.