# LINQ - What is the discriminator?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've written a linq query to get a couple of values from the database.

```
Dim query = From tit In db.Table1
            Join hol In db.Table2
            On tit.Id Equals hol.Id
            Join tran In db.Table3
            On tit.Id Equals tran.Old_Id
            Select hol.Id, tit.name_id
```

But when I enumerate the sequence, I get the following error twice: 
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.

There are piecemeal explanations of discriminators in other questions, but I'm still somewhat at a loss as to what the discriminator is, why it's there, and hopefully that will help me understand why my query is runs into an error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553935/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator-but-no-inheritance

Comment: See also [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 1 – Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)