# 42703: column Extent1.Discriminator does not exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework

I am getting this error when I perform a linq query on appusers table.

```
   var x = db.appusers.Where(y => y.AppUserID == 2).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: this sounds like an inheritance problem. have you applied all migrations?

Comment: Have you using Code First Migrations or Database/Model First? Can you provide example table structure, generated query string & stack trace to help us analyze your issue? Sounds like the column name is not exist in EDM data model.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro that was exactly the problem. Thank you. There was a `person` class from which class A was inherited and I further inherited it into B. Not sure why that is problematic. But it solved my problem.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes but now its solved , it had to do with inheritance.

Comment: The problem was that you've apparently recently introduced this inheritance and the database did not reflect this change.

Comment: probably `appuser` model is created by extending another POCO model. Turns out that Entity Framework will assume that any class that inherits from a POCO class that is mapped to a table on the database requires a Discriminator column, even if the derived class will not be saved to the DB. Look at this answer for solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586990/1349365)