# REST-Api with Entity Framework CORE / MSSQL server: Compute and return additional field/attribute at runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

## Intro and sample data

First of all, I want to apologize for the unspecific title. Since I have spent a lot of time on solving this problem (Google, SO, trial & error), I have come to a point at which I don't even know whether I am close to a solution or not.

My basic problem: I want to create a REST-Api with .NET Core which returns entities in a certain distance to a user.

#### SQL

Let's assume I have a table called **Museums** which has the following columns:

```
+------------+---------------+
|    name    |     type      |
+------------+---------------+
| Id         | int           |
| MuseumName | nvarchar(max) |
| Location   | geography     |
+------------+---------------+
```

#### Model

The belonging .NET Core model looks like this:

```
    public class MuseumModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string MuseumName { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Geometry Location { get; set; }
    }
```

### The problem

Now I want to create a REST-Api which returns museums based on a user's location and a max distance. Let's assume an Api call like this: `Museums/ByLocation?Latitude=50.114034&Longitude=8.679355&distance=1000`. The elements returned with the JSON should contain **Id**, **MuseumName** and **Distance**. In addition to that, they should be *ordered by the distance*.

**Main Problem**: Where should I compute that location stuff. In my eyes there are 3 theoretical options where the computing can be done:

- SQL
- REST-Api
- Native Client (in my eyes this is not really in option because I would need to transfer all museums first)

*Until now I was trying to do the computing with the SQL server. Are there any arguments against this?*

#### Idea A (logic at controller, computing on DB)

First of all I tried to solve the problem in the controller of the REST-Api:

```
var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
Geometry userLocation = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

return await _context.Museums
       .Where(x => x.Location.IsWithinDistance(userLocation, distance))
       .OrderBy(x => x.Location.Distance(userLocation))
       .ToListAsync();
```

**Problem A.1)**: I am asking myself if the computing time is optimal here since `IsWithinDistance` and `Distance` are called separately. Does the SQL server optimize this query?

**Problem A.2)**: How can I easily add the **Distance** to the resulting JSON? In this example the distance is thrown away after the computing.

#### Idea B (stored procedure called by controller)

My second approach was a stored procedure on the SQL server which basically adds the field `DistanceToUser` to the SELECT statement. The SP looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MuseumsWithDistanceToUser]
    @latitude float,
    @longitutde float
AS
    DECLARE @userLocation geography;
    SET @userLocation = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+CONVERT([varchar](20),@longitutde)+' '+CONVERT([varchar](20),@latitude)+')', 4326);
    SELECT *, DistanceToUser = Location.STDistance(@userLocation) FROM [dbo].[Museums]
GO
```

With this approach I think I have solved problem A.1 because the computing should be optimized. The resulting table now contains the `DistanceToUser` column but unfortunately there is a new problem...

**Problem B.1)**: The new problem is that I am not able to cast the data into the model. I even created a new model `MuseumWithDistanceToUserModel : MuseumModel` with the attribute `DistanceToUser` but this approach resulted in [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553935/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator-but-no-inheritance) and adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute is not possible because basically the new model is mapped to the SP.


*If you think this is the way to go, I can share the code and the occurring problems.* ***But is this a good solution at all?***

### Conclusion

I know I could do the WHERE and ORDER BY statements within the stored procedure and create a new model without any inheritance. But this seems kind of not clean to me. In addition to that I still want to be able to manipulate the query at the controller. Editing the SP on the DB each time there an adjustment is necessary is not preferred.
Please share any thoughts you have on this. I am grateful for everything :)

Comment: I'll never forget the time when I was learning MVC and I was so pleased at it's simplicity and straightforwardness..until I learnt about ViewModels..... huh? There's no letter for that in MVC? Regardless, it's a thing, and I believe it's the thing you're looking for to solve problem B1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: Processing in the application vs processing in the database is a discussion from the dawn of time. Personally I prefer database because my T-SQL is better than my C#. The answer below say that your C# is actually doing it in the DB anyway and I believe him. Don't get too hung up on performance for small numbers of records (i.e. 10,000 records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is, you are not clear about entity framework(EF) and stored procedures(SP). Both are same in big picture. EF is converting your code to sql query, execute it and return result.

SP, it is stored in sql server, when you call it, it will give results. Then you need to map those results to a model(c#).

Therefore at the end it will execute the same query.

And apart from both methods, you can run the query directly using EF.

```
public async Task<List<Museum>> GetMuseumsByRadius(Point point, double radius){
     return await _context.MuseumTemp
        .FromSql("SELECT Id, MuseumName, ST_Distance(Location::geography, ST_GeomFromText({0}, 4326)) as DistanceToUser  
                  FROM Museums 
                  WHERE ST_Distance(Location::geography, ST_GeomFromText({0}, 4326)) <= {1}"
                , point.AsText(), radius)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Distance)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
}

public class MuseumTemp
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string MuseumName { get; set; }

    public double? DistanceToUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

public virtual DbSet<MuseumTemp> MuseumTemps { get; set; }

// convert lnt,lat to a point
    Point userPoint = new Point(lng, lat)
    {
        SRID = 4326
    };
```

Alternative, This will generate optimal query by efcore. You can get generated query using web server out put (VS) or sql server profiler.

```
return await _context.Museums
       .Where(x => x.Location.IsWithinDistance(userLocation, distance))
       .OrderBy(x => x.Location.Distance(userLocation))
       .Select(e => new MuseumModel
                    {
                        Id  = e.Id,
                        MuseumName  = e.MuseumName 
                        DistanceToUser  = e.Location.Distance(userLocation)
                    })
       .ToListAsync();

public class MuseumModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string MuseumName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double? DistanceToUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Geometry Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this code throws another error. I am clear that EF can handle SP like tables and your example code is working (with some adjustements). **But it is not solving my problem**. Since you have modified the model of the Museum, all my other methods (which do not have anything to do with a user distance) throw "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'DistanceToUser'." This is the problem I can't solve. **How do I change the model temporary for that one specific endpoint?**

Comment: You can use another model and register that in context. see code change.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought about an additional class as well. This is a solution but then I have to maintain two models. When I tried to work with inheritance I ran into the error described in **Problem B.1)**. So how can I map *MuseumTemp* which inherits from *Museum* without the discriminator column in *Museum*?

Comment: Rule here is entity must have properties that in select statement. Fixing discriminator is an another story here. There is a work around to keep use original model. see alternative way