# Invalid column name 'Discriminator'. when inheritance parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5

**Main Class**

```
Class TimeMaster  {
     Public string parameter1 { get; set; }
     Public string parameter2{  get; set; }
     Public string parameter3 { get; set; }
   }
```

I wanted  backup of TimeMaster table  so I created BTimeMaster table **for backup** so **BTimeMaster**  class   use all main table parameter and one added  acdemicyear parameter extra.

**Backup Class**

```
    public class BTimeMaster : TimeMaster
    {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
      [DisplayName("AcademicYear")]
      public string AcademicYear { get; set; }
   }
```

**but when I called following function**

```
         var firstContext = new TimetableContext();
        foreach (var first in firstContext.TimeMaster)
        {

        }
```

***I cannot used like below if added [NotMapped] in class BTimeMaster*** and also want to map to a field and class BTimeMaster on the DB.

```
  var SecondContext = new BackupContext();
    foreach (var secondin SecondContext.BTimeMaster)
    {

    }
```

Error showed

[image]

***which step I missed when inheritance for parent class when used [NotMapped] for AcademicYear then it worked but i wanted AcademicYear for my backup table***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Code First "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" but no inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553935/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator-but-no-inheritance)

Comment: @KlausGütter  not work if added [NotMapped] i cannot add in  backup table   *BTimeMaster* is another table where inherit  some parameter and add addtional for backup table

Comment: @marc_s   Is good way two use parent class parameter for secondary class