# Using Inherited Entity Class in asp.net EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have following Entity Class (Which mapped directly to table of SQL Server DB)

```
public class PROCESSCARD : BaseClass
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Card No")]
        public String ProcessCardID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Entry Date")]
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Job Type")]
        public String JobType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job / Non Job")]
        public String JobNonJob { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Cost Booking")]
        public String CostBooking { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Planned Hrs/Qty")]
        public Decimal? PlannedHours { get; set; }
}
```

Above class inherits from BaseClass which is as follow

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public String StatusMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

Now upto this there is no issue everything is just fine,
but I am storing deleted data of entity PROCESSCARD to PROCESSCARD_HIST, and I want to show deleted history data to user.
Structures of both entity (PROCESSCARD and PROCESSCARD_HIST are ditto same) so I created another entity class PROCESSCARD_HIST, and to avoid duplicate members, I inherited PROCESSCARD_HIST from PROCESSCARD,

```
public class PROCESS_CARD_HIST : PROCESS_CARD
        {
    
        }
```

but now when I try to access data from PROCESSCARD_HIST class, it throws error like "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'",
Any Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your database DTOs aren't your business model entities. Inheritance in ORMs implies a relation between tables - 1) all subtypes in the same table with a discriminator column 2) all types in separate tables or 3) the base type in one table and all extra columns in separate tables per type

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the properties in both classes, introduce another unmapped superclass

```
    public class ProcessCardBase : BaseClass
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Card No")]
        public String ProcessCardID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Entry Date")]
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Job Type")]
        public String JobType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job / Non Job")]
        public String JobNonJob { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Cost Booking")]
        public String CostBooking { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Planned Hrs/Qty")]
        public Decimal? PlannedHours { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
public class ProcessCard : ProcessCardBase
{
    
}

public class ProcessCardHistory : ProcessCardBase
{
    
}
```